# Storing start and end times of a process using sqlalchemy subtract time from DATETIME

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a flask server and I want to be able to store the time at which the request was started and the time at which it ended. Since it is better for the database to manage time, I thought I would do something like this

At the start of the request

```
start_time = time.now()
```

At the start of the request

```
time_taken = time.now() - start_time
```

Then do something like this when initialising my log item:

```
class LogItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'log_items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    endpoint = Column(String, nullable=False)
    methods = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status_code = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    start_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_time = Column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, uuid, endpoint, methods, status_code, time_taken):
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.methods = str(list(methods))
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.start_time = # >>>>> something like func.current_timestamp() - time_taken <<<<<
```

So the end_time is set using the current time according to the database, but the start time should be something like `current time - time_taken`.

How can I achieve this

Comment: Have you tried `func.current_timestamp() - time_taken`? It should work pretty much as is, if `time_taken` is a `timedelta` object. So instead of `time.now()` use `datetime.utcnow()`.

Comment: and postgres will do the subtraction? not python. So `func.current_timestamp() - time_taken` will be executed by the database?

Comment: It is a subtraction.  It is very simple.  Why is it relevant who does it?

Comment: just because it should be using postgres' timestamp, not a timestamp that the python code generates

Comment: Yes. How SQLAlchemy SQL expression objects work and how they overload operators is [explained in the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#operators). In short: `func.something()` creates a `FunctionElement` object, which is also a `ColumnElement` that has `ColumnOperators`. Subtracting from that actually creates a new SQL expression object with the subtracted value as a bind param. Your DB-API implementation should know how to handle a `timedelta`. Another aspect of this is that you can pass expressions as values when adding model objects to DB.

Comment: `time.now()` ALSO is executed by postgres I believe